# Making a square-matrix of positions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, multidimensional-array

I've tried to make an n*n matrix such that 
if n = 2 the resulting matrix would be:

```
[[(1, 1), (1, 2)], [(2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

That is, the matrix of available positions in a 2*2 matrix.

I tried the following:

```
myIndex :: Int -> [[(Int, Int)]]
myIndex (n+1) n  =  []
myIndex 1     n  =  [zip [1, 1..] [1, 2..n]] ++ myIndex 2 n
```

But something is wrong. What exactly is wrong?

For clarity consider another example with n = 3:

```
[[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], [(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)], [(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly what is "wrong"? For a start, `myIndex (n + 1) n` is not valid syntax. And the whole thing is better done with `map` anyway...

Comment: @Koterpillar do you know how can i do that ? I tried to do this through 2-3 hours but i couldnt figure it out

Comment: `matrix n = map (\i -> map (i, ) [1..n]) [1..n]`

Comment: @leventov thanks a lot but are u sure that i can write a tuple like (i, ) ??

Comment: With a `{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}` pragma, you can, but it's not standard indeed! See [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/PthariensFlame/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#tuplesections) for more.

Comment: @caesar_ `((,) i)` instead of `(i, )` is standard.

Comment: @caesar_ addition in the pattern matching is called n+k patterns and are generally thought to be a bad thing.  They are off by default in new compilers, I think with a language pragma to turn them on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want a list of lists of elements like `(x, y)` where x and y are in `[1..n]`. Let's just write that:

```
myIndex n = map (\x -> map (\y -> (x, y)) [1..n]) [1..n]
```

Another way of saying the same is list comprehensions:

```
myIndex n = [ [(x, y) | y <- [1..n]] | x <- [1..n] ]
```